# Calling a method in one fragment from another

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, fragment

I've been trying for a while already (as well, searching in here) for something to help me to refresh listView in my MainFragment, when a button is pressed in other fragment. Could sommeone explain me how to make it work?

Here's MainFragment with the function (I excluded other functions, since I don't see how they contribute):

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
public void otherList() {
    SQLite db = new SQLite(getActivity());
    db.open();
    Calendar sCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String day = sCalendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
            Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH);
    Cursor c = db.getAllRecords(day);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    arrayOfBars.clear();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String country = c.getString(0);
            String city = c.getString(1);
            String bar = c.getString(2);
            String timeStart = c.getString(3);

            String[] h = timeStart.split(":");
            int times = Integer.parseInt(h[0]);

            String timeEnd = c.getString(4);
            String[] h2 = timeEnd.split(":");
            int timee = Integer.parseInt(h2[0]);

            String placeLaLo = c.getString(5);
            String description = c.getString(6);
            String likes = c.getString(7);
            String offer = c.getString(8);

            if (hour < (times + 1) || hour < (timee)) {
                getPrefs = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainFragment.this
                                .getActivity());
                boolean lay = getPrefs.getBoolean("boolean", false);
                if (lay == true) {
                    while (times < timee) {
                        timeStart = times + ":" + h[1];
                        times++;
                        timeEnd = times + ":" + h2[1];
                        arrayOfBars.add(new BarObject(country, city, bar,
                                timeStart, timeEnd, placeLaLo, description,
                                likes, offer, bar));
                    }
                } else {
                    arrayOfBars.add(new BarObject(country, city, bar,
                            timeStart, timeEnd, placeLaLo, description,
                            likes, offer, bar));
                }
            }

        } while (c.moveToNext());

        Collections.sort(arrayOfBars, new BarObject.CompST());

        lv2.setAdapter(null);
        adapter = new BarAdapter(getActivity(), arrayOfBars);
        lv2.setAdapter(adapter);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No database found",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    db.close();
}
```

}

And here's the other fragment:

```
public class SocialMedia extends Fragment {
ImageButton facebook, twitter, layoutS;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.social_media, container, false);
    layoutS = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ibLayout);

    layoutS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(SocialMedia.this
                            .getActivity());
            boolean lay = getPrefs.getBoolean("boolean", false);
            SharedPreferences.Editor e = getPrefs.edit();
            lay = !lay;
            e.putBoolean("boolean", lay);
            e.commit();
                            //Here I want to call otherList() from MainFragment
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: `FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    MainFragment fragem = (MainFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment);
    fragem.otherList();`,

Worked for me

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); 
MainFragment fragm = (MainFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment); 
fragm.otherList();
```

This code worked best for me. And seems quite easy

Comment: what is R.id.main_fragment? fragment layout or layout which fragment in loaded?"I have fragment in viewpager"

Comment: @JamaldinSabirjanov have you figured it out? My app just crashes when I use this code...

Comment: @JMB No, I made the variables "public static" and use them from another fragments.

Comment: main_fragment is not defined findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment)??? this is an incomplete answer.

Comment: ... one problem thow ... nobody knows how to set up fragment ID ... no solid docs on that at all

Answer (score 15):

In MainFragment class you can do the following code:

```
private static MainFragment instance = null;

@Override  
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    instance = this;  
}

public static MainFragment getInstance() {  
    return instance;  
}
```

And in SocialMedia class you can call the method as follows:

```
MainFragment.getInstance().otherList();
```

Comment: It shows this warning:
Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)

Answer (score 5):

you should use `interface` for this. define an `interface` in `OtherFragment` class and implement that in your `MainActivity` and define a `public` method in your `MainFragment` for refreshing your `ListView` and call that method from your `MainActivity`. here is an example :

```
public Class OtherFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

private Communicator communicator;

   ...

public void setCommunicator(Communicator communicator) {
    this.communicator = communicator;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   communicator.clicked();
}

   public interface Communicator {
      public void clicked();
   }
}
```

and in your `MainActivity` :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OtherFragment.Communicator {

   MainFragment mainFragment;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
      ...
      OtherFragment otherFragment = new OtherFragment();
      otherFragment.setCommunicator(this);
      ...
   }

   ...

   @Override 
   public void clicked() {
     mainFragment.updateList();
   }
}
```

and in your `MainFragment` :

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    public void updateList() {
        // update list
    }
}
```

Comment: to be honest I will not try to implement it, since I found a simple solution in the mean time. Thank you for the contributed time

Comment: @KManos What is the simple solution ?

Answer (score 0):

To call a method from another object (a Fragment is an object) you need to have the reference of that object. So if you want to call `MainFragment#otherList()` from a `SocialMedia` instance, `SocialMedia` needs a reference to `MainFragment`.

For example:

```
public class SocialMedia {

    private MainFragment mainFragment = null;

    public void setMainFragment(final MainFragment mainFragment) {
        this.mainFragment = mainFragment
    }
}
```

Then you can use `this.mainFragment.otherList()`.

Comment: I think it's not a good solution to pass a `Fragment` to another `Fragment`

Comment: Didn't work - it just crashed my app. But I did find a simple solution in the mean time.

Comment: @KManos It crashed probaby because you didn't set the fragment and it's null.

Comment: @KManos Then you should post your solution so we can all learn :)

Comment: I think it's against encapsulation and if you use this method, your fragments are no longer modular and you can't use them in some where else in your application.

Comment: @m0skit0 just did in the comment below my question

Comment: @m0skit0 please see my answer.I really appreciate if you let me know about your idea on my solution :)

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani Yes, you are right. I think your solution has the same problem btw: you can't use OtherFragment without a Communicator. You just try to hide the problem by using an interface, but the result is the same. Btw you could have just used OnClickListener instead of a new interface.

Comment: @KManos You should post it as an answer I think, your solution is better than mine and Mohammad's and it is indeed the right way to do it.

Comment: @m0skit0 it's the real use of interfaces. and if you want to use that fragment any where, you can easily use it, and add your custom functionality to that button.

Answer (score 0):

```
            // Calling Parent Fragment method from Child Fragment.
        // Child Fragment
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        NavigateFragment navigateFragment = (NavigateFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_place_dashboard);
        navigateFragment.sayHelloWorld();


        // -- Some method in Parent Fragment(NavigateFragment).
        public void sayHelloWorld(){
            Log.d(TAG, "Hello World.");
        }
```